# How can I determine the proper stressing of words?

Tags: pronunciation, emphasis, syllables

I am working on a sonnet.  This pretty much mandates the use of iambic pentameter and therefore requires that I have a good grip on emphasis.

However, I'm not exactly sure how to properly research words for emphasis.  I was attempting to comprehend Merriam-Webster's [Pronunciation Guide](http://www.merriam-webster.com/help/pronguide.htm), but that just further confused me.

Merriam-Webster has a system for indicating the stressing of syllables; almost every page has a set of symbols delimited by backslashes, describing the word's emphasis.

I was wondering if anyone experienced in the emphasis and or word pronunciation could help me understand this notation with an example or two.

Comment: Have a look at [these systems for denoting stress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_%28linguistics%29#Notation). I find M-W's notation confusing; if you agree, you may prefer a dictionary that uses IPA, like [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stipulate#Pronunciation) (here's today's word of the day as an example) or [OAAD](http://oaadonline.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/stipulate).

Comment: We could all just switch to speaking Hungarian. Then there'd be no question about where the stress goes in a word: it'd always go on the first syllable. :D

Comment: I propose renaming the site Hungarian.SE.  It would make some things a lot simpler.

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend [Stephen Fry's "The Ode Less Travelled"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1592403115). He starts by explaining the various rhythms of iambic pentameter, including all the various substitutions and how to use them effectively, and provides exercises to help you.

I wrote [a poem about software development](http://lizkeogh.com/2011/06/30/deliberate-discovery-a-sonnet/) in Iambic Pentameter recently after reading this book. Iambic pentameter normally follows this rhythm:

> da-DA da-DA da-DA da-DA da-DA

Or, using the notation you suggested:

> da da' da da' da da' da da' da da'

An *iamb* is a foot, and there are five of them, hence *pentameter*. You can occasionally substitute the iambs, and it's also OK to put a falling note after the last iamb since most words in English end that way. Hopefully my poem provides you with some examples of this, but I would still recommend the book.

Comment: A 'leg'? Don't you mean 'foot'?

Comment: I *thought* foot, and typed leg. Obviously there's a problem somewhere between my keyboard and my chair. Thank you.

Comment: I second the recommendation of *The Ode Less Travelled.* (Preferably get both the audiobook and the text version, so that you can hear the parts you need to hear, and read the parts you don't.)

Comment: If you second the recommendation then an upvote would be nice ;)

Comment: "If only we had known from the beginning...The ignorance we found along the way." Very nice.

Comment: Thank you. I'm aiming for the "Unsung Hero" badge here too.